# Navbar subelement ignore the css rule

Tags: css

I want a Dropdown navbar. But the style sheet not work for the drop down element. The elements should be vertical and not horizontal for the sub menue.

Here you can see the code. It is from w3schools. The only change is that add a class name to ensure that this rules are only fot this navbar.

But the submenue ignore now my style sheet like block and color.

Any idea?

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G42IHSMIFQAA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just deleted the `display: inline-block;` over the **`ul.topnav li a, .dropbtn`**, as you'd force the elements to be side-by-side, and rather, use `display: block;` so they can obey the `float: left;` parameter that you want.

```css
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}

ul.topnav li a, .dropbtn {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

ul.topnav li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!